# SQLCL Batch Scripting : Auto Connection + EXPORT CSV

Tags: batch-file, scripting, export-to-csv, sqlcl

SQLCL is exactly what I need, but I've a big difficulty on one little thing :

I want to make a script (batch file) with Auto connection and just after an EXPORT CSV (on a remote desktop : not on the server).

So I'm using the pipe method with SQLCL in a Batch File:

```
echo SET SQLFORMAT CSV <
echo SPOOL export.csv <
echo SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ARTICLE; <
echo SPOOL OFF | C:\Work\Soft\sqlcl\bin\sql.exe login/passwd@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:1521/DB.SCH
```

It's working (no errors in console) but, impossible to find the file `export.csv` : when I change the destination `c:\...` it's working too but impossible to find the created file. It's working fine with SQL Developer and the file is created on my dekstop, so I don't understand why it's not the same case for SQLCL.

Comment: What are you expecting the `<` to do in the script?

Comment: It's was the biggest error in my script, I had confusing between parallel command and escape char.

Comment: In your script add "cd /path/to/where/you/want/the/file" otherwise it'll end up in the C:\Work\Soft\sqlcl\bin\ folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the answer from the oracle Platform :

```
@echo off  
echo SET SQLFORMAT CSV ^& ^  
echo SET FEEDBACK OFF ^& ^  
echo SPOOL export.csv ^& ^  
echo SELECT COUNT^(*^) FROM dual ^& ^  
echo SPOOL OFF |  C:\Work\Soft\sqlcl\bin\sql.exe sql -noupdates -s -l login/passwd@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:1521/DB.SCH
```

Thank to Gaz in Oz